# Xcode 4 and wrong "Semantic Issues" - How to deal with them?

Tags: xcode4, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I've started using Xcode 4, and I'm really annoyed by some of the "features" especially those semantic warnings which don't seem to be making much sense, for example:

http://coding-journal.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Screen-Shot-2011-08-07-at-8.50.46-PM.png

On line 640, you can see a semantic issue saying that I am passing an incompatible pointer type to a parameter of `NSString *`, which is just plain wrong because the signature of NSTabViewItems' `initWithIdentifier:` is:

```
- (id)initWithIdentifier:(id)identifier
```

My guess is that Xcode thinks that I am calling `initWithIdentifer:` on some other object, because when I `Cmd+Click` the method, it gives me three options:

http://coding-journal.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Screen-Shot-2011-08-07-at-8.50.24-PM.png

And the first one, from NSTableColumn, has the signature

```
- (id)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

---

**So my question is, what do I do in this situation? I like my code warning-free, but this doesn't seem to be possible when using Xcode 4 :(**

Comment: i have this problem too, really want to know why xcode hates me.

Comment: What if you explicitly cast it to id?  (id)aTab

Comment: This has happened to me for many Xcode versions now, where Xcode seems to ignore a header and complain about it while in general use, but when I run a build it finds all the symbols and it is fine. I don't know why it complains when builds are fine. Very annoying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode "Use of undeclared identifier" errors, compiles/runs just fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150024/xcode-use-of-undeclared-identifier-errors-compiles-runs-just-fine)