# Xcode errors appearing after successful build

Tags: xcode

I'm building an iOS 7 app to run on iPads and iPhones.  The physical devices I have for testing are an iPhone 5 and an iPad 2.

This has all been working fine but recently, a new issue has appeared.

After I build for the iPad, Xcode's title bar says that my build was successful - but then, a second or two later, a red circle with an exclamation mark appears on the right end of the title bar  indicating that I have 'issues' (currently, 6.

This only occurs when I am building for the iPad.  The emulator and the iPhone builds do not do this.

The iPad build, itself, appears fine.  I can load it onto the iPad and run and debug it.  I can see the effects of my latest changes in code there so I know I'm not running a older version.

If I click on the red circle in the Xcode title bar, I'm shown what the 'issues' are and they seen very unlikely to me.

An example:

```
extern PIMG gImage; <-- complaint: Unknown type name 'PIMG'
```

I use the PIMG symbol all over my code.  The code is identical for both the iPhone and the iPad and the iPhone builds this fine.  If I replace the symbol with 'UIImage *'; which is what it symbolizes, and then rebuild, this partucular line no longer gives me trouble but the others continue to appear.

And note, that after I replace PIMG with UIImage * and rebuild, there still remain dozens of other instances of the PIMG symbol scattered through my code that are not provoking errors.

In an effort to fix these issues, I have done Cleans before I build and I have gone to the Organizer and cleared the derived data for this project.

None of these actions seem to have any effect.

I know that Xcode is constantly working in the background.  If, for example, I change a variable name at the top of a subroutine, XCode knows that I've done this quite quickly and it shows me that variables lower down are now undefined and highlights them.

I'm wondering if it is this background system that is getting confused about whether or not my symbols are all resolving correctly.

Any thoughts on what might be happening and how to further debug it?

Comment: I found the answer to this problem [here][1] in question 12150024 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150024/xcode-use-of-undeclared-identifier-errors-compiles-runs-just-fine