# XCode6 cannot create archive?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, testflight, xcode6.1

I have a project which works just fine in the simulator and on the real devices (iPhone 5, iPhone 4 and iPad) but when I try to create an archive (I would like to make an .IPA for TestFlight) there are errors which appear only in one file. I have similar code into other files but there everything is ok.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using a bridging header to import the Objective-C class files into your project?

Comment: Yes, I do and I added a screenshot. Thank you about pointing for this. It works perfectly in the simulator or in the device but the archive cannot build because of these errors.

Comment: Download latest SVProgressHUD and check once. There is difference in SVProgressHUD for 5 and 6

Comment: I am with the latest version - Using SVProgressHUD (1.1.2)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150024/xcode-use-of-undeclared-identifier-errors-compiles-runs-just-fine) might help you. Not sure if it's the same problem you're having.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I checked all the suggestions but no one of these fixed my problem. I think that If I had some kind of linking error I would not succeed building the project on the phone and in the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

I donno if this would be an answer..I dont have enough reputation to comment..so I am writing it here..
I think you also need to add bolts.framework along with parse.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was doing wrong:

I set the destination to the bridging header file for Debug mode but not for Relese one and for this reason everything works with the simulator and the real device when only testing but for TestFlight it couldn't find the headers.

Thank you for everyone for the help!

[image]